# undefined name for floating icon

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a to do list app but when I tried to create a new icon I would only get an error saying that the name is undefined.
This section of code is meant to take the data input by the user and save it.

```
submitData() {
  floatingIcon = new Icon(Icons.arrow_back);
  Task = [];
  TaskDesc = [];
  dynamicList.forEach((widget) => Task.add(widget.Task.text));
  dynamicList.forEach((widget) => TaskDesc.add(widget.TaskDesc.text));
  setState() {
    print(Task.length);
    sendData() {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

in the end of your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Hi I have tried updating the pubspec.yaml file but still gives the same error. Any further suggestions?